# Running Multiple argument docker not giving an output

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi

I am following an online tutorial on setting up a node. However, after reaching the last step, which is to create the docker, I can't advance anymore due to what I think is a beginners mistake from both sides.

I am trying this on Raspberry pi, with docker version  18.09.0, build 4d60db4.

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped -p 28967:28967 \
    -e WALLET="0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -e EMAIL="user@example.com" \
    -e ADDRESS="domain.ddns.net:28967" \
    -e BANDWIDTH="2TB" \
    -e STORAGE="2TB" \
    -v "<identity-dir>":/app/identity \
    -v "<storage-dir>":/app/config \
    --name storagenode storjlabs/storagenode:arm
```

After filling in my information (wallet address, ...etc.) and pressing return. 
I get no output from the terminal:
[image: Terminal output]

Please bare in mind that I am new to linux and docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your docker with the `-d` option, which creates your container **detached** mode without any log following. If you want to see the log output, simply remove this flag; otherwise, if you run with the `-d` option, you should follow the logs with `docker logs -f [container_id]` and that should show you all the container log outputs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped -p 28967:28967 \
    -e WALLET="0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -e EMAIL="user@example.com" \
    -e ADDRESS="domain.ddns.net:28967" \
    -e BANDWIDTH="2TB" \
    -e STORAGE="2TB" \
    -v "<identity-dir>":/app/identity \
    -v "<storage-dir>":/app/config \
    --name storagenode storjlabs/storagenode:arm
```

Works for me. Probably you were missing a closing `"`. Can you try your command again double checking if all double quotes are correct?

Comment: Yes .. I checked like a 100 times.

Comment: You can see my actual input in the image